# Escape % symbol in a java string to apply String.format

Tags: java, string, string.format, sanitization

In my project (Java/Play framework) I have an error handling routing that checks the response from a web service if the response is an error code, we display the corresponding error message saying what was the problem with the user input, the service checks user input validity.

When the user enter an % symbol, this logic breaks because the error display logic uses

```
String.format(message, messageArgs);
```

Which interpolates the messageArgs intro the message String where it finds an %, and if the messageArgs contains an % as well I get an exception.

I need to sanitize, escape or otherwise remove the % from the user inputs, before displaying the message.

message: The requested email address %s is invalid 
messageArgs: orlybg%@gmail.com

Any advice on how to do this in Java in the simplest, shortest way?

here's a part of the error log

```
 java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'i'
   at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Formatter.java:2646)
   at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2675)
   at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2528)
   at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2469)
   at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2423)
   at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2797)
   at controllers.api.PublicAPI.renderAPIError(PublicAPI.java:176)
   at controllers.api.DeviceAPI.setEmailAddress(DeviceAPI.java:736)
   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:557)
   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:508)
   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:484)
   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:479)
   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
   at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the error message? I don't think presence of `%` in `messageArgs` will be any issue.

Comment: Can you post an example of input that fails?

Comment: Ready just edited the post

Comment: It will be an issue if use String#format

Comment: I don't get what you mean @archer

Comment: Hmm. You need to show us the format string - `message`, and `messageArg` for which input fails.

Comment: Is this one @RohitJain

message:
The requested email address %s is invalid  

messageArgs:
orlybg%@gmail.com

Comment: Those inputs can't give the exception you have shown.

Answer (score 8):

In **message** String, the % sign is escaped with another %. So you will need to double it up: %%
For example: "Bla bla %i bla" -> "Bla bla %%i bla"
In **messageArgs** String, there is no problem with the % sign and you don't need to escape it

Answer (score 7):

Use `%%` in the formatter string when you need to print string `%`:

```
String.format("sendOneSuccessCountRate: %7.2f%%"
              ,sendOneSuccessCountRate //0.95
             );
```

will give you 95.00%

Answer (score 1):

If you receive `java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'i'` most possibly you use `%i` in your `message` trying to format an integer, this is not correct. You must use `%d` to format the deciamal integer. Full supported conversion specification could be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).